# AWS CLI command to copy specific files from S3 to local or hdfs

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am trying to copy a list of some files from my S3 bucket to local or my `hdfs.My` Bucket has more than 220000 objects and I just want to copy file starting with `abc2018-` to my local system. The list of files in `abc2018-` is more than 20k.
I just took a sample file and tried copying it using the below command and I got succeeded:
 `s3cmd get "s3://bucketname/abc2018-01-02.txt" ~/`

If I want to copy all files with abc2018- to a home folder I don't have an option.
Do I need to write any script or it can be achieved with s3cmd itself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try to use AWC Cli:

```
    aws s3 cp s3://bucketname/ ~/ --exclude "*" --include "abc2018-*" --recursive
```

This command copy only the pattern you want.
Enjoy!

Comment: When I try this I dont see any files being downloaded. What's bizzare is the Taskmanager shows that there is some download happeing. The download speed hit 2+ Mbps and remain there. After a few seconds even the upload speed go up almost upto 1Mpbs. I am just trying to download 2 files whose size is approx 500kb.  Any idea what could be happeing?